# How do I run and Ubuntu desktop in EC2?

Tags: cloud, aws

we have implemented a cloud using the ubuntu server and amazon ,we installed the uec image given by amazon of ubuntu 9.04 ,we were successfull in accessing through the terminal by using it as ubuntu@ but failed to virtualize the environment like we get in the virtual box on client system. please suggest me a way

Answer (score 1):

I run 12.04 as a Free Cloud Desktop on AWS EC2 all constantly on the Free Tier Micro instance model. I have run Ubuntu Virtual Cloud Desktops on EC2 for years using The FreeNX software. NX Web Companion (for Browser enabled) and NX local client for machines where I can install the software instead of run the java piece. Also, added an RDP (Remote Desktop Protocol) for easier Windows access.

A little configuration work but easy once you understand it. It works well, though the web enablement is a little clunky. I am trying to find a better model on this post:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/258919/any-ideas-on-a-better-browser-enabled-cloud-desktop-using-ubuntu-12-04-gnome-an

Anyone can ping me if they want to see more about how it works. Here is how it is setup on AWS:

https://www.desktopanywhere.com/free_cloud_desktop/setup-your-desktop/setup-details/

Love AWS and Ubuntu

Comment: There is a new much improved AMI available using Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (Xenial Xerus) using Amazon Web Services (AWS EC2) that is super easy to spin up and is a Free Cloud Desktop. You can check it out here and get a copy if you like: https://www.desktopanywhere.com/free_cloud_desktop/